# upload image to folder and insert path to database and text files in php

Tags: php, image-uploading

```
<?php
error_reporting( ~E_NOTICE );
require_once 'dbconfig.php';

if($_POST)
{
  $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
  $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
  $description = $_POST['description'];
  $election_name=$_POST['election_name'];
  $category_name=$_POST['category_name'];

  $imgFile = $_FILES['user_image']['name'];
  $tmp_dir = $_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'];
  echo $imgSize = $_FILES['user_image']['size'];

  $upload_dir = 'user_images'; // upload directory

  $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension

  // valid image extensions
  $valid_extensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extensions

  // rename uploading image
  $photo = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;

  // allow valid image file formats
  if(in_array($valid_extensions,$imgExt)) {            

    // Check file size '5MB'
    if($imgSize > 5000000) { 
      move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,"$upload_dir/$imgFile");
        try {

          $stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO candidate(firstname,lastname,description,election_name,category_name,photo) VALUES(:ename, :edept, :esalary, :elect, :cat, :ima)");
          $stmt->bindParam(":ename", $firstname);
          $stmt->bindParam(":edept", $lastname);
          $stmt->bindParam(":esalary", $description);
          $stmt->bindParam(":elect", $election_name);
          $stmt->bindParam(":cat", $category_name);
          $stmt->bindParam(":ima", $photo);

          if($stmt->execute())
          {
              echo "Successfully Added";
          }
          else{
              echo "Query Problem";
          }   
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    }
  }
  else {
      echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";     
  }
?>
```

I have this code to upload image and text files but it say Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed. I've tried to solve this many times but i can't find solution on my own, please suggest the correct way of doing this.

Comment: .txt files are not in your allowed extension array...

Comment: which file are you upload?

Comment: What Happened? Problem Solved?

Comment: still the problem exists

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
 if (in_array($valid_extensions, $imgExt)) {
```

To

```
 if (in_array($imgExt,$valid_extensions)) {
```

[**`in_array`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) need first parameter as search value and second parameter as your array

You always return false value and you got that error

Comment: thank you all i just changed like that but still says Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed .

Comment: WHat is your file name which you have to upload??

Comment: <input class="form-control" type="file" name="user_image"  required />

Comment: previous one is input form for uploading  image  my file type is. jpg in my computer

Comment: `echo   $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));` // get image extension
and paste its value

Comment: i just past file path like this  echo $imgExt="E:\Arch wisdom\cool-modern-architecture-buildings1.jpg"; and then it echos E:\Arch wisdom\cool-modern-architecture-buildings1.jpg and says sorry only....

Answer (score 0):

just add `txt` extension in ur aarray

```
$valid_extensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add .txt extension in your code like this,

```
$valid_extensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif','.txt');
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You just correct your code in this line:

```
$valid_extensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif','txt'); // valid extensions
```

it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(in_array($imgExt,$valid_extensions))     
$valid_extensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif','txt');
```

You will need to modify code with this code...

Answer (score 0):

This code will insert image in a folder and path in database:

```
<?php
$grocery=$_POST['grocery'];
$connect=new mysqli("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($connect,'go-web');
$target_dir = "..images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        die("File is not an image.");
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    die("Sorry, file already exists.");
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    die("Sorry, your file is too large.");
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" ) {
    die("Sorry, only JPG, JPEG & PNG files are allowed.");
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    die("Sorry, your file was not uploaded.");
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        die("Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.");
    }
    }
    $query=mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO product VALUES ('$grocery','$target_file')");
    if($query)
    echo "Uploaded";
?>*
```

Answer (score 0):

According To Me,

**1)** You wrote text files is also getting uploaded. But, no text files extension added to `$valid_extensions`.

Change To

```
$valid_extensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif','txt'); // valid extensions
```

**2)** As **@Saty** answered, you need to swap your parameter in

`if (in_array($valid_extensions, $imgExt)) {`

as

`if (in_array($imgExt,$valid_extensions)) {`

First parameter act as `Search Value` and Second Parameter as `Search Array`.