# how can i upload this new generated image to my localhost/images/

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to publish an image that generated by my steganography web. So here is the current flow.

1. User choose an image for the steganography
2. User input their message
3. Web will generate new image that already have that message inside `<img>` tag

**How can I upload this new generated image to my localhost/images/ ?**

**Expected behavior:**

After the image is generated user will press publish button, it will create a post request and also upload the generated image to desired location.

```
<img src="" id="final_image" class="img-thumbnail">
```

I have the generated image here. and currently have to move manually by, right click > save as > desired destination.

Comment: first decide JavaScript or Php ? both are different.

Comment: i will use php instead, so after the user click the generate button i will also create a post request and upload the generated image

Comment: you can check this my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38392740/upload-image-to-folder-and-insert-path-to-database-and-text-files-in-php/38392903#38392903

Comment: sorry, but its a normal upload, the thing is i want to upload the image that generated by the web @Lokesh

Comment: upload to where ? upload in the profile ?

Comment: upload to my server, eg: localhost/images/stegano_image

Comment: that's what I have done there. I have just added another step of storing the image file location in database. which you can omit that

Comment: so what you've done there is upload the actual file, not the generated one. for example. I upload file called a.png and then my web modify that file to a1.png, what i want to upload is a1.png

Comment: I guess you are changing the file name and then trying to upload right ?

Comment: not the file name, its the pixel value of the file because i'm doing steganography. so basically i want to modify the content of the file then upload it

Comment: then you might like this http://thedebuggers.com/image-steganography-hiding-text-using-php/

Comment: and also this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290259/detect-main-colors-in-an-image-with-php

Comment: in that case your question should not be like `how can i upload this new generated image to my localhost/images/` you should ask how could you generate the steganography image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the image and convert to base64 using js or jQuery and save base64 image as file using php like this

```
$data = 'data:image/png;base64,AAAFBfj42Pj4';

list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);

file_put_contents('/tmp/image.png', $data);
```

Comment: is in this solution i have to upload the original file and then rewrite it with the one that i generated? , base on this http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: you can check this(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146954/replace-file-in-php)

Comment: it works thanks!!!, so i upload the original image first, and then rewrite it with the base64 string, i don't get it at first. but thanks